# Double value in excel cell if an "*" is present

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an array in excel. 6 cells accross, 4 down. Which will be used to input scores from a quiz.

Is there a way that I can input an " * " (asterisk) next to the score in the cell and have excel automatically double the value, removing the " * "?

Comment: Not with conditional formatting, only with VBA.

Comment: You can also do it in a different cell with formulas, but to do it in place at the time of change it can only be done with vba in a Worksheet_Change event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple VBA code. Modify it per your needs,

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
If InStr(target.Value, "*") > 0 Then
    target.Value = Left(target.Value, InStr(target.Value, "*") - 1) * 2
End If
End Sub
```

This code uses a change event to detect changes to cells. If there is any `*`, the value will be automatically doubled